# How do I write a bare-metal RISC-V program to go from boot to writing to the UART0 on QEMU's `sifive_e` machine?

Tags: qemu, riscv, riscv32, qemu-device

## Background

I'm trying to understand the boot process for a simple RISC-V computer in detail.
I'm not interested in getting all the way to an operating system: I just want to know what happens between poweron and running a bare-metal program to write some data to the UART device.

Since booting is hardware-specific, I picked the SiFive [HiFive1 RevB](https://www.sifive.com/boards/hifive1-rev-b) because:

- It's relatively cheap
- It has both real hardware and can be emulated via QEMU's `sifive_e` machine

(However, if there is a more appropriate board, I would also like to know)

My goal is to understand all of the code involved in the boot process. I am particularly confused about the role of the following:

- Firmware
- The bootloader
- QEMU's `-bios` flag
- QEMU's `-kernel` flag

### Desired outcome

As proof that I understand all the pieces going into the boot process, I would like to write a program which writes "Hello World" to the UART0 device, and then halts (either with a busy loop, or somehow by powering off the board).

Ideally, I would write all the pieces needed to make this happen in RISC-V assembly. I would also like to avoid using any high level languages, toolchains, and linkers.

## A working version for the QEMU `virt` machine

I have a simple program which works as expected on QEMU's `virt` machine.
It's a binary file `test.bin` of RISC-V instructions produced by a python script--it is not produced by gcc or another compiler.

Here is the contents of the file according to objdump:

```
> objdump -b binary --architecture=riscv -D test.bin

test.bin:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   00100093                li      ra,1
   4:   01c09093                slli    ra,ra,0x1c
   8:   01300113                li      sp,19
   c:   00c11113                slli    sp,sp,0xc
  10:   04800113                li      sp,72
  14:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
  18:   06500113                li      sp,101
  1c:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
  20:   06c00113                li      sp,108
  24:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
  28:   06c00113                li      sp,108
  2c:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
  30:   06f00113                li      sp,111
  34:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
...snip
```

This generates the UART0 address (`0x10000000`) of the `virt` machine and places it in register `R1`.
It then simply writes each byte of "Hello, World" to that address.

I run this file as follows:

```
> qemu-system-riscv32 -nographic -machine virt -bios test.bin
Hello, World!
QEMU 7.1.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) quit
```

The final two lines of output here are because QEMU appears to hang, and I use `C-a c; quit` to exit.

I can also run the image using the `-kernel` flag:

```
> qemu-system-riscv32 -nographic -machine virt -kernel test.bin
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
...
```

In this case, it loops printing "Hello World" until I quit.
I assume this is because the `virt` machine has a default bios which sets up handlers for illegal instructions and restarts my program: since `test.bin` does not busy loop at the end, this triggers the handler and restarts.

### Question 1

- If I use `-bios test.bin`, is my code the first code running when the CPU boots, or does some other code run first? (For example "firmware")
- Is there a "firmware stage" that happens before the BIOS?
- What does the default `-bios` for QEMU's `virt` machine do?

## Porting to the `sifive_e` machine

I expected that I could just port this code to the `sifive_e` machine by changing the UART0 address to [`0x10013000`](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/riscv/sifive_e.c#L61)

Here is the objdump for the modified code `sifive_e.bin`, which computes the UART address by adding together `R1` and `R2`:

```
   0:   00100093                li      ra,1
   4:   01c09093                slli    ra,ra,0x1c
   8:   01300113                li      sp,19
   c:   00c11113                slli    sp,sp,0xc
  10:   002080b3                add     ra,ra,sp
  14:   04800113                li      sp,72
  18:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
  1c:   06500113                li      sp,101
  20:   00208023                sb      sp,0(ra)
```

However, when I run this as follows:

```
qemu-system-riscv32 -nographic -machine sifive_e -bios sifive_e.bin
```

QEMU produces no output and appears to hang. This is also the case if I run it like this:

```
qemu-system-riscv32 -nographic -machine sifive_e -kernel sifive_e.bin
```

### Question 2

- What is missing to make this example work on the `sifive_e` machine?
- Where can I find documentation on the boot process for `sifive_e`?
- Does the boot process of the QEMU `sifive_e` machine really correspond to that of the `HiFive1 RevB` board?

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: These are part of the same question imo, I only added these bullet points to highlight what I don't understand